# Reading integers from file and storing them into arrays and writing in a file

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

```
// id         scores
    2000    62  40
    3199    92  97
    4012    75  65
    6547    89  81
    1017    95  95
    7714    85  83
    1234    91  76//AG_midterm.txt
```

Tasks: Read data from file, discard the student ID, calculate the average of the two midterm exams, and store it into an array
and write the average in another file(AG_sorted.txt)

I am facing errors and i cant seem to figure out the problems. I've tried my best to be as neat as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50

// Function declarations
void printInfo();
int readresults(FILE *AG_Midterm, int *score1, int *score2);
void sort(float* avgScore);
void calcAvg (FILE *AG_Midterm, float* avgScore, int score1, int score2);
void writeSortedResults (FILE* AG_Sorted, float* avgScore);
void printdone();

int main (void)
{
// Local Declarations
    FILE* AG_Midterm;
    FILE* AG_Sorted;

    int score1[MAX_SIZE];
    int score2[MAX_SIZE];

    float avgScore[MAX_SIZE];

// Statements
    printInfo();

    if(!(AG_Midterm = fopen ("/Users/r3spectak/Desktop/AG_Midterm.txt", "r")))
        {
          printf("\aError opening Results File\n");
          return 100;

        } // if open input

    if(!(AG_Sorted = fopen ("/Users/r3spectak/Desktop/AG_Sorted.txt","w")))
       {
          printf("\aError opening Average Results file\n");
          return 102;
        }// if open input

    while(readresults(AG_Midterm, score1, score1))
        {
          calcAvg(AG_Midterm,&avgScore,score1,score2);
          sort(avgScore);
          writeSortedResults(AG_Sorted, avgScore);

        } //while

    fclose (AG_Midterm);
    fclose (AG_Sorted);

    printdone();
    return 0;

} // main

/*==================printInfo==================================
    Reads data from Midterm file
    Pre : Nothing
    Post: Prints introduction message
*/
void printInfo()

{
// Statements
    printf("Begin Calculation of Scores\n");
    return ;
} // printInfo


/*===================readResults==================================
    Reads data from employee file
    Pre : spEmp is an open file.
          empID,dept,payrate,exempt,hours worked
    Post: reads Employee ID and Pay rate
          if data read -- returns 1
          if EOF or error--returns 0
*/

int readresults(FILE *AG_Midterm, int *score1, int *score2)
{
// Statements

  int i;
  int items;

  for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE && (items = fscanf(AG_Midterm, "%*d%d%d", score1 + i, score2 + i)) != EOF;
      i++) {
    if (items != 2) {
      printf( "Error reading data\n");
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
} //readresults

void sort(float*avgScore)
{

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i< MAX_SIZE; i++);

    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if(avgScore[i] < avgScore[j])
            {
               //Exchange them
            int temp = avgScore[i];
                avgScore[i] = avgScore[j];
                avgScore[j] = temp;
            }
       }
   }
return;

} // sort


/*===================calcAvg==================================
    Determines the Average of the two midterm scores
    Pre : score1, score2
    Post: avgScore copied to addresses

*/

void calcAvg (FILE *AG_Midterm, float* avgScore, int score1 , int score2)

{
    int i=0;
// Statements
   while (i<MAX_SIZE && fscanf(AG_Midterm,"%*d %d %d", &score1, &score2)!=EOF)
   {
       avgScore[i] = (score1 + score2)/2.0;
       i++;
   }

} // calcAvg


/*===================writeSortedResults==================================
    Writes Average Scores after Sorting
    Pre : AG_Sorted is an open file
          avgScore
    Post: Data written to file
*/
void writeSortedResults (FILE* AG_Sorted, float* avgScore)
{

// Statements
    fprintf(AG_Sorted, "%f\n", avgScore);
    return;


} // writeSortedResults

/*==================printDone==================================
    Reads data from Midterm Score File
    Pre : Nothing
    Post: Prints end message
*/
void printdone()

{
// Statements
    printf("End of Average Score\n");
    return;
} // printDone
```

Comment: ***"I am facing errors"*** - what kind of errors? how did you try to solve them?

Comment: while(readresults(AG_Midterm, &score1, &score1))
        {
          calcAvg(&avgScore,score1,score2);
          sort(&avgScore);
          writeavgResults(AG_Sorted, avgScore);


.............error: cannot convert 'int (*)[50]' to 'int*' for argument '2' to 'int readresults(FILE*, int*, int*)'|

Comment: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[50]' to 'int*' for argument '2' to 'int readresults(FILE*, int*, int*)'|

Comment: Prototype which u declared on the top for calcAvg is not proper when using for the its definition

Comment: Note that the declaration `void printdone();` says there is a function called `printdone()` that doesn't return a value and which takes any number of arguments of any type (but the list is fixed, not variable).  It does not mean the same thing as `void printdone(void);` which says the function takes no arguments.  (In C++, the first declaration means the same as the second, but C is not C++).  For symmetry with the declaration, the definition should probably start `void printdone(void) { ... }`, though it is not crucial.

Comment: yeah i dont think it changes anything with the problems i am facing now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code generally, repeatedly confuses data with the addresses of data.  For example, the line

```
while(readresults(AG_Midterm, &score1, &score1))
```

should read

```
while(readresults(AG_Midterm, score1, score1))
```

So, the problem seems to be a general conceptual problem rather than a bug, and you're probably not in a position to address it, yet.  You might try something much simpler, first, and work your way back up to this code.  (If it's a homework assignment due in the morning, as it looks, then the hour is late:  you probably cannot learn what you need to know in one evening.  Hopefully, this answer at least points you to the right part of your textbook.  Good luck.)

Comment: calcAvg(avgScore,score1,score2); now faces another problem.
|error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void calcAvg(float*, int, int)'|
|error:   initializing argument 3 of 'void calcAvg(float*, int, int)'|error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void calcAvg(float*, int, int)'|

Comment: The definition of `calcAvg()` has 4 arguments, but the declaration and use only have 3 arguments.

Comment: That's right, and if you fix that error, the compiler will report another one -- and if you fix all the errors on this basis, your code probably won't do anything useful.  One hopes that you'll take no offense if I observe that you don't seem to understand the overall problem, that you seem to be in over your head, and that you need to spend a few days, or weeks, working simpler problems before you tackle this one.  Of course, I could be wrong about that, but your question as asked admits no simple, straightforward answer.

Comment: calcAvg(AG_Midterm,&avgScore,score1,score2);
error: cannot convert 'float (*)[50]' to 'float*' for argument '2' to 'void calcAvg(FILE*, float*, int, int)'|

i dont understand why there is a problem here